# ASP.NET Authenticate as someone else

Tags: security, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-membership

I am about to develop an ASP.NET MVC 3 site where there will be two different kinds of users: Global Administrator and Local Administrator.

A local administrator can administrate his own data. The global administrator can select a local administrator and sort-of "simulate" being that user. By this, I mean that he shoud preferably be able to see the same views etc.

What are your thoughts on how this behavior could be implemented?

Best Regards
Kenneth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using [forms authentication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647070.aspx) you could impersonate any user:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "admin")]
public ActionResult BecomeGlobalAdmin()
{
    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie("globaladmin", false);
    return RedirectToAction("index");
}
```

You might also want to store some information into the session which would indicate that the user is in fact an administrator but acting as a global administrator (if you need such functionality).

Comment: Hm yea, it seems it could essentially be that simple. Thanks so far, I'll try to go down that route later in the day.